# Jupyter refuses to serve hidden directory (D:\) on windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to launch Jupyter with a base directory being the root of my second hard drive. I used to be able to do that just fine with Ipython 3.x until I upgraded to the latest version.

If I cd to D:\ and type `jupyter notebook --debug` the end of the trace I get is:

```
[I 12:15:14.792 NotebookApp] Refusing to serve hidden directory, via 404 Error
[D 12:15:14.792 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[W 12:15:14.813 NotebookApp] 404 GET /tree (::1) 23.00ms referer=None
[D 12:15:15.062 NotebookApp] 304 GET /custom/custom.css (::1) 152.00ms
```

I've tried running the command from an elevated command prompt but to no avail.

**How can I run jupyter at the root of my D:\ drive on Windows?**

Comment: this [pull request](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/1168) aims to fix this bug. It's not working yet on Windows but I'm sure it's just a matter of time.

Answer (score 10):

I've been unable to run it in the root of any drive, but it works fine from any subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Unfortunately, I don't think this should be classified as an answer, because my question was how can I run it at the root of a drive.

Comment: I think the answer is that you can't, and that the error message doesn't indicate the reason for the failure adequately. While it's not a solution, it's a workaround. Thanks, kinverarity.

Answer (score 3):

As kinverarity advised, any attempt to use the root folder directly will say that it's refusing to serve a hidden directory. If you absolutely must serve from the root folder (but can change how you try to run it), then what you will need to do is to create a symlink folder pointing to the root, so you run it from what it thinks is a folder but it serves files from the root. The following command creates a notebooks symlink:

```
mklink /D notebooks \
```

cd into the symlink folder and run jupyter and the error goes away but it's still serving the files from root.

I should point out that you want to make sure you don't have any processes that iterate recursively over all folders on the drive (unless they skip symlinks), otherwise they'll iterate into the notebooks folder, its notebooks folder, etc, and will never complete because it'll get stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to see hidden files and folders by launching `jupyter lab` from the command line with the following command:

`jupyter lab --ContentsManager.allow_hidden=True`

To do this I:

- Click the `Anaconda3 (64-bit) menu, then
- Click the `Anaconda3 Prompt (anaconda3)` from the Windows menu.
- I pasted in the command above and hit `Enter.`

The default web browser loads with the `jupyter lab` interface and I can see hidden files and folders. Specifically I am using the to see the hidden `.aws` directory.

Comment: This worked for me on `Linux`, where I create my own `JupyterLab` environment via `python` and `pip install` of `Jupyter` and `JupyterLab` packages (in other words, I create my environment manually). This solution worked in that context. Odd. I've been doing this for years, and this is the first time I've seen this issue. It's probably related to some recent underlying change.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on a Ubuntu 16.04 setup.  I thought I'd post this in case it helps someone out.
Turns out its a permissions thing for me.
in my case, the original permissions were 755 (read,write,exec for the owner; read, exec for the group and read, exec for guests)
I changed this setting to 666 which is rw for everyone and it threw the error reported above.  By changing it back to the original settings, everything worked fine. I know this is a windows complaint, but I'd suggest it may be permissions related to the directory you story your scripts in (your working directory)

Answer (score 0):

a few days ago i had same problem . When you arrange files sharing rules in windows machine , python files can be being hidden unknowingly while you want to hide another files , too .

if jupyter files are in the hidden files like i mentioned above , it has solved by doing this steps;

1. Go to computer ,
2. Hit Alt on the keyboard
3. and then hit Tools tab
4. Select Files Option from the tools tab
5. Select view tab from opened Files Option screen
6. Hit Show hidden files radio button at the Advanced tab

After doing these steps , this problem had solved in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -f notebook
```

solved this for me