# can't see hidden folder in jupyter notebook tree

Tags: jupyter-notebook, hidden-files

when I launch my jupyter notebook using anaconda, I can't see none of my hidder folder (folders starting with a "." ex : .myfolder) is it normal ? and is there a way to be able to access the notebooks within a hidden folder ?

Comment: Please see my answer to this duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366624/jupyter-refuses-to-serve-hidden-directory-d-on-windows/68262572#68262572